# Can't get GlassFish 3.1 Final get to work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I tried GlassFish 4.0 and 3.1 Final in Eclipse Juno & Kepler, but I can't get it work. I downloaded GlassFish Tools for Kepler/Juno on Eclipse Market. If i try to run it's just loading until the time runs out. In directory "glassfish 3.1\glassfish3\bin" I opened "asadmin.bat" and tried with "start-domain" code and It already happened that the server started, but sometimes it's just infinite loading. When the server started I opened "localhost:4848" in browser and all i get is "Status: The Admin Console application is loaded." which is loading infinite (if i refresh the page it goes blank doing nothing).. I run windows 7 Professional N 64x.

Any idea what should i do?

EDIT: I tried the same setting on my friend's computer and it works, but i need this on mine!
And i got these errors:

> Blockquote SEVERE: SEC5054: Certificate has expired:
>
> Blockquote SEVERE: DPL8015: Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [_*admingui]. Line 116 Column 42 -- src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>   SEVERE: DPL8005: Deployment Descriptor parsing failure : src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>   SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [*_admingui]
>   SEVERE: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/E:/Šola/2.Letnik/2.Semester/Praktikum/Projekt%20po%20roku/glassfish%203.1/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_0.xsd; lineNumber: 116; columnNumber: 42; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [__admingui].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/E:/Šola/2.Letnik/2.Semester/Praktikum/Projekt%20po%20roku/glassfish%203.1/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_0.xsd; lineNumber: 116; columnNumber: 42; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [__admingui].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:188)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:93)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:826)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:768)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:364)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/E:/Šola/2.Letnik/2.Semester/Praktikum/Projekt%20po%20roku/glassfish%203.1/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_0.xsd; lineNumber: 116; columnNumber: 42; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [__admingui].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:315)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:236)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:639)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:376)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:246)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:255)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:216)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:180)  ... 7 moreCaused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/Šola/2.Letnik/2.Semester/Praktikum/Projekt%20po%20roku/glassfish%203.1/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_0.xsd; lineNumber: 116; columnNumber: 42; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4124)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4107)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1730)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:405)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1422)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:619)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:588)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2448)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1767)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:309)    ... 15 more

SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [__admingui]

Answer (score 4):

And try to install into directory WITH ONLY LATIN CHARACTERS in path to Glassfish. I had Glassfish in directory with Cyrillic folder name and it didn't start because of this error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/C:/Users/Сергей/Downloads/glassfish-4.1-web/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_0.xsd; lineNumber: 116; columnNumber: 42; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [__admingui].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-appType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Then I moved it to 'F:\'  without 'Сергей' in folder path and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling Glassfish in a path that does not contain spaces.
There may also be an issue with the version of the Glassfish Tools that are on the Eclipse Marketplace (I've never been able to get it working when installed from there), I would double-check and make sure the Glassfish Tools you got from the Eclipse Marketplace are the same that came from this update server: `http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/12.1.2.1/kepler`

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip :) I was going mad with GlassFish not working without an apparent reason and almost given up until I saw this post and fixed it in 30 seconds

+1

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Glassfish 5 instead.